# Where can I ask about definitions of words to understand laws that pertain to computer professionals?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In California employment law, there is a term called "system design specifications."  Attorneys have told me to ask technical I.T. people what this means as there is no legal definition for it.

An excerpt of the law (CA Labor Code Section 515.5) says this:
"The design, development, documentation, analysis, creation, testing, or modification of computer systems or programs, including prototypes, based on and related to user or system design specifications."

I understand what is says except for "system design specifications."  Where can I post a question about what "system design specifications" are?

Answer (score 2):

The right place for these kind of questions is [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com). From their [help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - Statutes or court decisions

Even if the question is IT related, legal matters are off-topic on Stack Overflow and [in most circumstances](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/what-types-of-legal-questions-are-on-topic-here) on Programmers.